# How to force Wix bundle be installed PerMachine?

Tags: wix, bundle

I have defined a bundle with several items in the Chain,
all items are marked ForcePerMachine="yes" for MsiPackage and PerMachine="yes" for ExePackage
but my bundle seems to be always installed in a PerUser mode.
How do I make it install as PerMachine ?
In installation log I see:

```
    Line 148: [A164:C924][2023-02-01T13:52:09]w322: Skipping cross-scope dependency registration on package: eonUninstaller, bundle scope: PerUser, package scope: PerMachine
    Line 156: [A164:C924][2023-02-01T13:52:09]w322: Skipping cross-scope dependency registration on package: LumenRTAppInstaller, bundle scope: PerUser, package scope: PerMachine
    Line 159: [A164:C924][2023-02-01T13:52:09]w322: Skipping cross-scope dependency registration on package: LumenRT_Content1, bundle scope: PerUser, package scope: PerMachine
    Line 160: [A164:C924][2023-02-01T13:52:09]w322: Skipping cross-scope dependency registration on package: LumenRT_Content2, bundle scope: PerUser, package scope: PerMachine
    Line 161: [A164:C924][2023-02-01T13:52:09]w322: Skipping cross-scope dependency registration on package: LumenRT_Content3, bundle scope: PerUser, package scope: PerMachine
    Line 162: [A164:C924][2023-02-01T13:52:09]w322: Skipping cross-scope dependency registration on package: LumenRT_Content4, bundle scope: PerUser, package scope: PerMachine
```

What I understood is: if all packages are set PerMachine, Bundle should also be set PerMachine.
So I make sure my MSI were set as PerMachine both in bundle xml and msi xml with InstallScope="perMachine".

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Something in your chain is flipping the bundle to per-user. I _think_ there is a verbose message from light.exe that will tell you when a package changes the bundle to per-user.

Comment: I did have this warning in previous build:
```
##[warning]light.exe(,): warning :  warning LGHT1140 : Bundle dependencies will not be registered on per-machine packages for a per-user bundle. Either make sure that all packages are installed per-machine, or author any per-machine dependencies as permanent packages.
````
I then fixed the issue. I don't have this warning anymore but bundle is still installed perUser.
Could that be related to register key creation or something like that ?

Comment: Not clear what is going awry but StackOverflow isn't really the place to have conversations about the problem. You might try the WiX Discussion forum on GitHub instead.

Comment: Ok, then let's switch to github there: I https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/discussions/7212